# Delete all index except one/some in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Is there any way to delete all indices except one?

We can use the metadata **_index** of document in a **GET** request:

```
GET _count
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "_index": "indexname"
    }
  }
}
```

The above query doesn't make sense but just to show that we can use **_index** inside a query I have mentioned it.

I have tried the below query, but I guess **_all** API doesn't support query.

```
DELETE _all
{
  "query" : {
  "bool" : {
   "must_not" : [
     {
       "match": {
         "_index": "indexname"
       }
     }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Is there any way to delete all indices except one/some without using bulk API ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use [multiple indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) syntax. You can specify all indices with `*` and then exclude some of them with `-`.

Suppose we need to remove all indices except `foo` and `bar`, so the HTTP request should be

```
curl -X DELETE -i 'http://{server}:{port}/*,-foo,-bar'
```